Iam having category class inside product class, when trying to use for loop and map it response DTO iam getting many outputs when i test the API
  ``public List<ProductResponseDTO> getallproducts() {
    List<Products> productsList= productRepository.findAll();
    List<ProductResponseDTO> productResponseDTOS = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Products p: productsList){
        ProductResponseDTO productResponseDTO = new ProductResponseDTO();
        productResponseDTO.setUuid(p.getUuid());
        productResponseDTO.setName(p.getName());
        productResponseDTO.setPrice(p.getPrice());
        productResponseDTO.setImage(p.getImage());
        productResponseDTO.setDescription(p.getDescription());
        productResponseDTO.setCategory(p.getCategory());

        productResponseDTOS.add(productResponseDTO);
    }
    
    return productResponseDTOS`;

Iam having category class inside product class, when trying to use for loop and map it response DTO iam getting many outputs when i try to test the API like below.. is this way of mapping correct
-->productResponseDTO.setCategory(p.getCategory());
[{"uuid":"30145429-3853-49ad-82af-18b8ba623c68","name":"Go pro Camera","price":10000.0,"category":{"uuid":"8a9c09e7-47ac-4b88-b6fa-5acc688c468e","name":"Electronics","products":[{"uuid":"30145429-3853-49ad-82af-18b8ba623c68","name":"Go pro Camera","price":10000.0,"category":{"uuid":"8a9c09e7-47ac-4b88-b6fa-5acc688c468e","name":"Electronics","products":[{"uuid":"30145429-3853-49ad-82af-18b8ba623c68","name":"Go pro Camera","price":10000.0,"category":{"uuid":"8a9c09e7-47ac-4b88-b6fa-5acc688c468e","name":"Electronics","products":[{"uuid":"30145429-3853-49ad-82af-18b8ba623c68","name":"Go pro Camera","price":10000.0,"category":{"uuid":"8a9c09e7-47ac-4b88-b6fa-5acc688c468e","name":"Electronics","products":[{"uuid":"30145429-3853-49ad-82af-18b8ba623c68","name":"Go pro Camera","price":10000.0,"category":{"uuid":"8a9c09e7-47ac-4b88-b6fa-5acc688c468e","name":"Electronics","products":[{"uuid":"30145429-3853-49ad-82af-18b8ba623c68","name":"Go pro Camera","price":10000.0,"category":{"uuid":"8a9c09e7-47ac-4b88-b6fa-5acc688c468e","name":"Electronics","products":[{"uuid":"30145429-3853-49ad-82af-18b8ba623c68","name":"Go pro Camera","price":10000.0,"category":{"uuid":"8a9c09e7-47ac-4b88-b6fa-5acc688c468e","name":"Electronics","products":[{"uuid":"30145429-3853-49ad-82af-18b8ba623c68","name":"Go pro Camera","price":10000.0,"category":{"uuid":"8a9c09e7-47ac-4b88-b6fa-`
